# Jenkis pipeline with extra credentials for ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have problem with conditions in `ansible`.
Here is my code sample:

```
// some code that generates result with lines
when: result.stdout_lines | length > 0
   block:
   - name: generates json
      // some magic
      register: jsonFile

   - name: processing json
     // some json parcing magic
     when condition in json
```

The problem is: `block` is using for all sub-tasks condition `when: result.stdout_lines | length > 0`
If sub-task has its own condition, `when: result.stdout_lines | length > 0` is dropped.
It is mentioned in [documentation for block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html)

So when `ansible` hits `when: result.stdout_lines | length > 0` it is trying to do `- name: processing json`.
`- name: processing json` fails, because `- name: generates json` wasn't executed.

But i don't want to execute this 2 tasks if result is empty.
What should i use instead of `block` to "hide" sub-tasks from execution?

`Ansible` version is 2.9

Answer (score 0):

you could use a second yaml-file `sub.yml` with plays in it:

```
- name: generates json
  // some magic
  register: jsonFile
- name: processing json
  // some json parcing magic
  when condition in json
```

and then call with include from the parent playbook:

```
  - name: i am the parent
    include: sub.yml
    when: result.stdout_lines | length > 0
```

Comment: also see [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+include+playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+include+playbook)

Comment: For my coded parts it will be to difficult to "extract" it in separate files.

Comment: I have also tested your proposition. It has same result. It fails cause of non initialized json.